# normalization weak entity with BCNF

Tags: database

how to Decompose FDs of weak entity into BCNF when it does not have primary key...
we could not define any function dependency!
for example we have these entites:

**user**(name,user_id)
**product**(product_type,cost,product_id)
**laptop**(cpu,time,user_have_id)
**mobile**(resolution,time,user_have_id)
**flash**(memory,time,user_have_id)

product_type,cost,product_id do not depend on any thing
I don't know how to work with weak entity
could't we design it in better way???